# How to pass Picklist value form one Visual Force page to another?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference

I have 2 visual force page that I need to pass value from each other. First visual force page is for opportunity edit page. In this page I have a picklist field called Type . Value of this field are One, Two, Three.

There is another field called car and its type is lookup on the Opportunity edit visual fource page. When someone clicks on this lookup I am redirecting them to visualforce page called Carlookup . On this Carlookup visualforce page I want the value of Type from previous page which has been selected by user.

Let me clarify few things here .

In my org I use `openPopup()` function  and pass paramenters into that like baseURL,Width,Heigh

where Variable baseurl is what I have created for different fileters in that lookup page.

Here is the code for Baseurl

```
var BaseURL="/apex/Looup?txt=" + txt; 

if(Cond.) 
    {baseurl = baseurl + "&txt2=" document.getElementbyId(page:form:pbs:carvalue).value;
```

i have tried adding another condition for type

```
if(opp.type != null) baseurl = baseurl+"&type=" + document.getElementbyId(page:form:pbs:Type).value; }
```

but this does not go inside if(opp.type != null) even if it is not null. I have debugged that by looking at the gerated url and it does not have no parameter called type.

Anyone please can help me with this? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try with if({!opp.type} != null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should work in following way

```
if('{opp.type}'!= null){
     baseurl = baseurl+"&type=" +document.getElementbyId("page:form:pbs:Type").value;
}
```

**Edit:**

To address openpoup() function having stopped working, try the following and check console for errors:

```
if(document.getElementbyId("page:form:pbs:Type").value!= null){ baseurl =
baseurl+"&type=" +document.getElementbyId("page:form:pbs:Type").value; } –
```

Comment: let me know if you see any error in console.

Comment: I did that and now openpoup() function has stopped working. it doesn't open the poup anymore.

Comment: there is no error in console

Comment: do you see any error in error console ?

Comment: No. There isn't any error in console

Comment: if(document.getElementbyId("page:form:pbs:Type").value!= null){
     baseurl = baseurl+"&type=" +document.getElementbyId("page:form:pbs:Type").value;
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30541/discussion-between-himanshu-and-ricky).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not refreshing your JavaScript when opp.Type value is update . So pass this value when you call this Javascript method. Something like

```
popup('{opp.type}')
```

Also check you are getting picklist value in your code or you can try something like.

```
var e = document.getElementById("page:form:pbs:Type");
var strValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

and then pass  this value in Parameter. So your complete Javascript method will look like

```
function popup(type) {
   var e = document.getElementById("page:form:pbs:Type");
    var strValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if(type != null){
        baseurl = baseurl+"&type=" +strValue ;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey Tushar. Where can I use popup('{opp.type}')

Comment: I already have one openpopup() in which I am passing baseurl width etc.

Comment: from where you are calling your JavaScript  method. pass value from your method openpopup('{opp.type}')

Comment: This is my Openpopup function
openPopup(baseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+width+",height=480,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);

should I add into this?

Comment: yes add into this.

Comment: Ok I have added into this. Now I can open popup. but cant see type in the url of that page

Comment: did you add that also in url. can you share your update code of `openPopup()` method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30543/discussion-between-ricky-and-tushar-sharma).

Comment: ya Sure. here is the openpopup() 

openPopup(baseURL, {opp.Type__c}, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+width+",height=480,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);

Comment: No the code of openPopup(); function the Javacsript function. share that code .

Comment: Hi did you get the code that I shared?